# Can't access Amazon S3 bucket after mounting using s3fs

Tags: macos, aws

I have been trying to mount an Amazon S3 bucket as a OSX volume using the s3fs command line tool (installed from Homebrew). The issue is that although I run the s3fs command as per the instructions ([here](http://blog.d3in.org/post/11915313724/mounting-an-s3-bucket-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard), for Mac-specific, or [here](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) more generally), and it returns no errors, when I attempt to cd to the mounted volume the I get the following error:

```
mkdir /Volumes/s3

sudo /usr/local/bin/s3fs mybucket /Volumes/s3
Password:

cd /Volumes/s3
cd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: 
No such file or directory
```

The install went off without a hitch, and all dependencies appeared to have installed correctly, so I don't think that that's an issue (obviously, I could be wrong). I also know that I can't simply mount the volume, as it is not in a file system native to OSX.

I know that s3fs isn't terribly well-documented for Mac users, but perhaps somebody here has some experience getting this to work. Thank you in advance.

I am using OSX Lion 10.7.4.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have permission to see that folder. Use `sudo -i` to become root and then try again.